# ASP.NET Identity - Create Custom Tables

Tags: asp.net-identity

I am starting a new application using ASP.NET Identity. I've watched the [ASP.NET Identity video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJ4WyOJ2oKc) from Microsoft and it was very helpful, but I still have a question that I can't find posted any place.

So I created the new application in Visual Studio 2013. It created the database template for me, just like in the video. He went into a lot of detail about how to add custom properties in the existing tables and then using PowerShell to add those changes.

I need to have additional tables in my database, that have nothing to do with the default tables. For example, if I was creating a forum software, I would use ASP.NET Identity to manage the user accounts, but I would also need tables similar to "Forums", "Threads", etc... which will hold the content for the Web site.

I am unsure how to go about creating these. I was planning on adding the extra tables using SQL Management Studio, just as I normally would, but I'm not sure if that's the correct way to do it. While these tables are independent from the identity data, they still need to communicate with the identity tables.

As an example, in the "Threads" table, I would need to have a field called "userid" to track the user that submitted the thread. That "userid" should be a FK to the AspNetUsers.id field in the database.

I'm well aware of how to do this using SQL Management Studio, but I wasn't sure if that was the "correct" way. I'm thinking that I should be creating these tables via code, like I did with the extended user properties, and then using PowerShell to migrate the changes into the database, but I have no idea how to do something like that.

I'm looking for some information as to how I should approach this. If I should just be creating them in SQL Management Studio, or if there is a method to create them via code within the solution itself.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you plan to use Entity Framework?

Comment: I wasn't planning on using it.

Comment: As long as you don't modify the Identity tables, then go ahead and create the other tables yourself in management studio with the FK to AspNetUsers. The PowerShell updates uses EF Migrations so you can safely ignore that.

Comment: The "correct" way really depends on the database API you will be using. You'll need to narrow down the scope of this question to get any kind of really useful answer.

Comment: I looked into the Entity Framework, and I think I will use that after all. It seems like it's going to be much easier, and should help resolve the problem I'm having. Thanks for the information.